# Nuxtjs hook system

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I wrote my own [module](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/modules/) for my [nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/) application. Since upgrading to **version 1.4.0** this line:

```
this.nuxt.plugin('close', () => new Promise((resolve) => server.close(resolve)))
```

generates following warning:

> nuxt.plugin('close',..) is deprecated. Use new hooks system.

However, there does not seem to be any documentation on this 'new hooks system'.
Can anybody tell me what I have to change?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: check this post https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2587#issuecomment-358736863

Comment: @divine thank you! Exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [new hooks](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/modules#run-tasks-on-specific-hooks) are invoked with: `this.nuxt.hook(NAME, FN)`.

```
// this.nuxt.plugin('close', () => {...})
this.nuxt.hook('close', () => {...})
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Schwesi No problem :)